# Using GSL lib functions on data in a struct C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, gsl

Many GSl functions take arguments as doubles or arrays of doubles. However much of my data is nested in arrays of structs instead. Say like arrays of:

```
struct A
{
  double a;
  int b;
};
```

I could write a wrapper that copies the data into an array of pure doubles or ints. But I was interested in something more elegant to get around this.

Comment: Example, just pass `array[i].a` or `array[i].b` where a `double` or `int` is required.

Comment: Yes this is a possibility. However it's my understanding that most problems are represented as in terms of structs (lots) of data units. One then works on arrays of such structs. What's the point exactly of putting an array in a struct, defeats the rationale of using structs in the first place.

Comment: No no. A struct allows you to coordinate differing `types` of data as a single object. When you have more than one of those struct (objects) to work with, an array of them makes perfect sense (and is very very common). Your comment is the reverse (an array within the struct). If one of those types you need to coordinate as a single object of data is an array -- then an array within a struct makes perfect sense (and is also very very common). It all depends on your data handling needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer you want. But since you cant change the GSL interface, if you are looking for performance, I think your best solution is probably to chose data structures that matches the job from the start.  So maybe something like a struct containing arrays of doubles.

If both the GSL interface and your original data structure is out of your control, then your only option is probably going to be the wrapper that you are thinking about.

If the library functions that you are using could take a 'stride' argument, you could possibly look into structure packing and padding. (But that still wouldn't convert your ints to doubles.)

Comment: I was looking at the stride argument. However the block that you're supposed to be passing has to contain double constitutents. It's really unbelievable they've brought in such fundamental flaws in the library. Careless or what. I would have structs, doubles, ints, chars in the block. They could have just used the damn offset of the variable in a given struct or arrays of structs. There is already an off the shelf library which allows this in stddef.h using offsetof.

Comment: it's not the answer I was looking for. But it's the best answer on the table.

Comment: The thing I like about C is that, for good and bad, it forces you as the developer to think about data structures and access patterns at the cost of convenience. The GSL API might seem inconvient, but there are reasons for most of the 'madness'.

Answer (score 1):

> "...much of my data is nested in arrays of structs instead. ... I
>   could write a wrapper that copies the data into an array of pure
>   doubles or ints. But I was interested in something more elegant to get
>   around this."

There is no need to write a wrapper to copy the data into an an array of pure `double` or `int`. The fact that you have an *array-of-struct* already provides convenient direct access to every stored value. With an *array-of-struct* accessing each individual `struct` within the array is a simple matter of indexing the struct you want, e.g. `array[n]` where `n` is the wanted element within the array.

In your example `array[n].a` provides direct access to the `double` value in member `a` and `array[n].b` provides direct access to the `int` member `b` for each of the valid index within  your array.

A short example of this indexing for direct access to each member of each struct within the array may help. The following initializes `array` with five struct with the `double` and `int` values shown. The `int` values are then incremented by `1` within the loop before each member of each struct is output, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct A {  /* struct A (with a typedef for convenience) */
    double a;
    int b;
} A;

int main (void) {

    /* array of struct A */
    A array[] = {{1.1, 1}, {2.2, 2}, {3.3, 3}, {4.4, 4}, {5.5, 5}};
    size_t nelem = sizeof array / sizeof *array;    /* no. elements */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++) { 
        array[i].b++;   /* increment int/output stored values */
        printf ("array[%zu]: {%3.1f, %d}\n", i, array[i].a, array[i].b);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Note how the integer value stored within each `struc` in the *array-of-struct* is incremented by `1` before the values in each `struct` with the array is directly used as the parameter being output by `printf`:

```
$ ./bin/arraystruct
array[0]: {1.1, 2}
array[1]: {2.2, 3}
array[2]: {3.3, 4}
array[3]: {4.4, 5}
array[4]: {5.5, 6}
```

Your access of each member regardless how you want to use it would be the same. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The implicit point in this question is that many gsl functions take arrays of data (double [] etc) as arguments, rather than feeding each value one at a time. The question is rather specific to gsl usage.